# Is it possible to set fixed y-axis to spline chart update every second

Tags: highcharts, angular2-highcharts

I am working on real time data stream with spline chart https://www.highcharts.com/demo/dynamic-update/dark-green. Here i want to set fixed y-axis scale (I know my data range from 0 to 4 max) but here chart update dynamically.

[image: spline chart update every second]

Is it possible to set fixed y-axis so that chart update as per fixed y-axis scale.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any axis you can set a minimum and a maximum value with `axis.min` ([doc](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.min))  and `axis.max` ([doc](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.max)). If you want to be very precise (or your ticks are causing problems) you might have to disable [`startOnTick`](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.startOnTick) and [`endOnTick`](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.endOnTick) to set your specific values, as described in the documentation of `min` and `max`.

For example ([JSFiddle demonstration](https://jsfiddle.net/m9x7fv8z/3/)):

```
yAxis: {
    min: 0.25,
    max: 0.75,
    startOnTick: false, // optional
    endOnTick: false, // optional
    // ...
}
```